# React attempted import error in node module

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules

I'm receiving the `next` error when trying to run my application, the `package.json` use `node v12.x` and my version installed is `v16.17.0`

> ./node_modules/@reactour/tour/dist/tour.esm.js
> Attempted import error: 'Portal' is not exported from '@reactour/utils'

I tried to update the `@reactour/utils` to `v3.1.6` but there are many breaking changes that I cannot deal with them right now, so I need to make it works with version

```
"@reactour/tour": "^2.13.0"
```

Any suggestions or workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

it is a  **default export**,  import it like this  :

```
import Portal from '@reactour/utils'
```

Comment: I can't because is from node_modeles

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Open package.json file.
2. Search '@reactour/tour'
3. Change the version to the latest. In my case I have changed to "3.2.1"

   "@reactour/tour": "3.2.1"
4. Run npm install

Answer (score 0):

My solution was use a different version of npm and node. I updated to use the latest but not for the library @reactour/utils I updated my npm and node.